# How do I randomly add letter in this 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

What code would i need to get a letter to randomly generate inside this code?

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create 2-dimensional array.
    int[][] values = new int[5][5];


    // Loop over top-level arrays.
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        // Loop and display sub-arrays.
        int[] sub = values[i];
        for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
        System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");


        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: u want to add random letters to fill up the array?

Comment: Not clear. What do you want as an output?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
//loop through rows
for(int x = 0; x< values[0].length;x++)
{
//loops through columns
   for(int y = 0; y< values.length;y++)
   { 
       int x = (int)(Math.random()*26); // random int between 0-25
       String letter = ""+s.charAt(x); //concatenates
       values[x][y] = letter; // declares.
   }
}
```

here is How you would get a letter to randomly generate inside the code.

Comment: Im not sure why you would want this. but this should work